# accessing a jpg which is not in the web folder through PHP

Tags: php, image, png, jpeg, gif

I recently found a youtube video that talked about accessing a PDF in a web browser. It was interesting because as I suspected I could access a PDF most anywhere on the system (given permissions) and pass it along via PHP to a web browser.

I do not want his to become a security discussion so please abstain from security comments!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4a6QJSGL28

The code looks something like this

```
$file="/home/kodi/Pictures/scans/test.pdf";
$filename="test.pdf";

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
@readfile($file);
```

So I tested and it works then I tried this

```
$file="/home/kodi/Pictures/scans/test.jpg";
$filename="test.jpg";

header('Content-type: application/jpg');
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
@readfile($file);
```

Oddly enough this did NOT display in a web browser, but several seconds later, my preferred app for downloaded jpgs opened and there was the file . It had downloaded instead of opening in browser.

I have been working on a LAN app that can access users folders on the server through PAM authentication and have been using base64 encoding, however I felt that if I could reduce the overhead of base64 images (30%) , conversions and literally converting each image in a list to display links to them, the system would load faster. This would definately be a better way but everyone says that this kind of thing does not work! The proof that there is hope that it will work ios in the file I downloaded from the web server that was in a user folder.

Any ideas how to make it work with jpgs?

Answer (score 0):

Your content type is incorrect, it should be image/jpeg, instead of application/jpg